# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier'

Tags: python, opencv

im using cv2 to try to take a picture here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_eye.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        #print(x,y,w,h)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        img_item = "my-image.png"
        cv2.imwrite(img_item, roi_color)
        stroke = 2
        color = (0, 255, 0)
        end_cord_x = x + w
        end_cord_y = y + h
        ecolor = (50, 50, 50)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (end_cord_x, end_cord_y), color, stroke)
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
          cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex,ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh), ecolor, 1)


cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i get the error:

> File "c:NothereForPrivacyReasons\imagerecognition\face\picture.py", line 3, in 
> face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CascadeClassifier'

Comment: If your file is in currently folder. You can do this face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml'). Otherwise you must specified drive path

Comment: If  on raspberry pi(llinux)f ace_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('../cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

Comment: maybe you have file with name `cv2.py` (or folder with name `cv2`) and it imports this file/folder instead of module `cv2` and it can't find `CascadeClassifier` in your file/folder. You have to rename your file/folder.

Comment: it is safer to use special variable `cv2.data.haarcascades` to access folder with files `.xml` - `cv2.CascadeClassifier( os.path.join(cv2.data.haarcascades, "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml") )`